# how i should make scrollbar overlaps the content and content have to be visible under it

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

How i should make scrollbar overlaps the content and content have to be visible under it?
So if I will have overflowed by y-axis and scrollbar will appear on the right side of my div because of `overflow: overlay`

I want to see the content under scrollbar, for example text, when I get my parent div overflowed-y and scrollbar appears on the right side of it and overlaps the content. (I'm using webkit scrollbar rules with transparent backgrounds and yellow scrollbar tumb)

Is it possible to do with pure css without external packages (at least usind webkit pseudo elements)?

Or if it's impossible, is there a possibility to do it with js/ts?

Comment: `How i should make scrollbar overlaps the content and content have to be visible under it?`
So you want a transparent scrollbar on top of the content?

Comment: I want to see the content under scrollbar, for example text, when I get my parent div overflowed-y and scrollbar appears on the right side of it and overlaps the content. (I'm using webkit scrollbar rules with transparent backgrounds and yellow scrollbar tumb).

Comment: As far as I know atleast Chrome has disabled the posibility of having the scrollbar going over content. The only way to enable it is by enabaling a flag. However you can't ask that of your users. You can however style the scrollbar but only in Chrome